# sequelize.js query joining two tables with a where clause on the joined table

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I’m trying to use sequelizejs to get the most recent blog post from a blog table, including all of the corresponding comments (from a separate comment table) that have been approved.   And the comments database has a field “blog_id” that has, well, the corresponding blog’s id.

If I do this:

```
models.blogs.hasMany(models.comments, {foreignKey:'blog_id'})
models.comments.belongsTo(models.blogs, {foreignKey:'blog_id'})
models.blogs.findAll({where:{id:id},order:"id DESC", limit:1,  include:    [{model: models.comments, where:{approved:true}}]}).then(function(blogs){
    res.json(blog:blogs[0])
});
```

the result is the most recent blog post which *has* a comment that has been approved, not the most recent blog post *and* any comments that have been approved.

My work around is to have two queries:

```
models.blogs.findAll({order:[["id","DESC"]],limit:1}).then(function(blogs){
    var blog = blogs[0];
    models.comments.findAll({where:{"blog_id":blog.id,"approved": true}}).then(function(comments){
        res.json({
            blog:blog,
            comments:comments
        })
    })
});
```

which is fine and functional but not elegant.

Just wondering what would be a one query solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need specify required false in your include , which as default is true.

```
models.blogs.findAll({
  where: {
    id: id
  },
  order: "id DESC",
  limit: 1,
  include: [{
    required : false, 
    model: models.comments,
    where: {
      approved: true
    }
  }]
})
.then(function(blogs) {
  res.json(blog: blogs[0])
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Gonzalo.  It makes sense and works.  In case anyone is reading this and using the code, I had to change the order line from my original code to: order:[["id","DESC"]]